# mule - how to run code on starting mule (server listener)

Tags: mule

I was reading this post

[MULE lifecycle - how to hook into startup process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269903/mule-lifecycle-how-to-hook-into-startup-process)

but I don't get how to put the xml in the mule-config.xml file.  I don't have a flow, inbound endpoint nor outbound endpoint.  I just have a class with a start and stop that I need to run some code on.  What is the mule xml for this?  I can't find any examples of this.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd">
        <spring:beans>
            <spring:bean id="initializer" class="org.myclass.that.implements.muleContextNotificationListener.MuleContextNotification"/>
        </spring:beans>

        <notifications>
            <notification event="CONTEXT"/>
            <notification-listener ref="initializer"/>
        </notifications>

    </mule>
```

(Inspired on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280908/singleton-startup-mule-component-flow/9282959#9282959))