# Consuming a web service in a MULE domain project

Tags: spring, web-services, parameters, mule, spring-bean

I'm developing a set of MULE 3.7.0 app projects under a MULE domain project which contains a set of shared parameters for all these apps and I need to consume an external webservice before any of the apps is loaded in order to get an additional parameter which is needed for all the apps and also for the domain itself.

As there are no flows in the domain project, I don't know how to achieve this.

Can this be done? If so, how? Maybe a bean-oriented approach?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per problem description provide here, you can go for Spring bean approach to achieve this. Check out similar post below.

[mule - how to run code on starting mule (server listener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845059/mule-how-to-run-code-on-starting-mule-server-listener)

Let me know if still facing any issues.

Comment: Thank you very much, Djoker. I didn't find that post in my previous search. It looks like it will suit. Thanks again!